# Add avatar to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a project in Ruby on rails; I just want to set a default avatar to users that have "@gmail.com" email address. I found the migration file but I'm not able to locate the file that set the default avatar. Is that possible with the migration file?

Thank you everyone

```
class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :decidim_users, :avatar, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you only set the default avatar to users once the email address has "@gmail.com", shouldn't it be done during saving or updating of user's info? Not during migration.

Comment: Default column values are fixed / constant. You can't set a column default that depends on another column. If the user doesn't have an avatar, it would probably be better to leave the `avatar` column / attribute empty and handle the fallback dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a generic default value for the `avatar` column but, in the migration file, you can't implement the logic you describe.

This logic should be inserted in the controller or model, regardless of the migration.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the answer. How can I understand where the migration comes from?

EDIT: how can I understand what is the function that creates the default avatar?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be great if you were a bit more discriptive names.

I don't think AddAvatarToUsers makes sense for this migration.

Anyway You can try this!:

```
class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :decidim_users, :avatar, :string, :default => "@gmail.com"
  end

  def self.down
    # You can't currently remove default values in Rails
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "Can't remove the default"
  end
end
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just want to set a default image for users that has @gmail.com account email and another image for users with other account emails. I'm not understandig what is the function that creates account. How can I do?

Comment: In that case probably you need a before_action for create in your decidimUser controller to set the avatar as something if user email contains @gmail.com

Comment: In case you are using devise you gotta overwrite the devise controller. Lemme know if you are still facing issues

Comment: I don't have devise, this is the problem, I'm not able to find the createUser function and I don't know how to find it, How can I do?

Comment: you probably gotta have decidim_users_controller.rb somewhere in your directory. in that file find the create method that is where you have to modify base on what you need!